# Macbook 2.1 maximum RAM?

Tags: mac, memory, macbook

I have a white macbook 2.1 model running 1,83GHz Intel Core 2 Duo...apple is setting a limit of 2Gb RAM on the specific model while some users claiming that up to 3Gb of memory can be usable is there any true in what users are claiming?anybody with experience on the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Mactracker](http://mactracker.ca), you can put 3 GB.

Comment: It even says "3.0 GB (actual) 2.0 GB (Apple)".